# Currency symbol is not displaying properly in PHP

Tags: php, currency

Currency symbol is not displaying properly.
Below is my code:

```
$total = "₮50.40";
echo $total."<br>"; //output: ₮50.40

$str3 = substr($total, 0, 1);

echo $str3; //output: �
```

The variable `$total` is displaying correctly. But I extracted the symbol from `$total` and display it, unfortunately it shows � .

I want to display ₮ from variable `$total`.
I tried `utf8` encoding, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `₮` character is a multi-byte character, so you need to use [`mb_substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php), not `substr`:

```
$total = "₮50.40";
$str3 = mb_substr($total, 0, 1);
echo $str3;
```

Output:

```
₮
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BjZea)